# Using `this` in Crockford's pseudoclassical inheritance pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've just read The Good Parts, and I'm slightly confused about something. Crockford's example of pseudoclassical inheritance goes like this:

```
var Mammal = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Mammal.prototype.get_name = function () {
    return this.name;
};
```

Part of the problem with this is that the constructor has "its guts hanging out" - the methods are outside of the constructor function. I don't see what's wrong with assigning `get_name` to `this` inside the constructor though. Is it because we'd end up with multiple copies of the `get_name` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's basically it.

By assigning them to the *prototype*, they will be *inherited* by all instances of `Mammal`: there will only be *one single* copy of those functions in the entire system, no matter how many `Mammal`s there are.